# Teradata SQL - Replacing special characters

Tags: sql, replace, teradata

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 for my reports.  My report runs, however, if a user exports the results to Excel (xlsx) instead of Excel 2003 (xls), they get an "illegal xml character" message when the file is open.

4 of the columns contain "&" and / or " ' "; so I'm trying to replace these special characters; which I believe are causing the issue.

I've tried to update this line:
j.journal_desc AS "Jrnl Description",

with this line:
oreplace(oreplace(j.journal_desc, ’&’, ‘and’),'''','') AS "Jrnl Description",

and it works fine.  However when I do this on a second line I get the message:  "SELECT Failed.  [9804] Response Row size or Constant Row size overflow".

I've tried "otranslate" and it works on 2 columns.  However, when I try it on the 3rd column, I get the same overflow message.

Is it possible to use oreplace or otranslate on multiple columns?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to replace these special characters?  t

Thanks for the help......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oreplace and otranslate when used the result string will have length of 8000 unicode characterset.each of otranslate will make much longer by 8000. Try to cast to smaller length should fix problem.

```
 CAST(oreplace(journal_desc,'&','and') AS VARCHAR(100))
```